# Column not found when using DB raw in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use `DB::raw()` in my eloquent query but it returns an error. Please see details below.

**Code**

```
$companies = Company::select([
        '*',
        DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(CONCAT('1/', month, '/', year), '%d/%M/%Y'), '%c-%d-%Y') as fullDate")
    ])
    ->whereBetween('fullDate', ['Aug-01-2019', 'Oct-01-2019'])
    ->count();
```

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fullDate' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: have you tried `having` instead of `where`

Comment: fullDate will not work with whereBetween() as you are selecting it as Aliases. Change whereBetween() with whereRaw() and add fullDate conditions in it. Then try again. I faced a similar problem and I was able to resolve it by doing so.

Comment: I'm getting the same error @KaleemShoukat

Comment: @Snapey I tried `having` but it returns incorrect results. I tried to check it but it seems like `having` use is for groupings of data.

Comment: You have distinct columns of year and month?

Comment: @Snapey No, I don't have any.

Comment: Show what your data looks like

Comment: @Snapey https://i.imgur.com/i2KlbzO.png

Answer (score -1):

Use mysql date formats;

```
$companies = Company::select([
        '*',
        DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(CONCAT('01/', month, '/', year), '%d/%M/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as fullDate")
    ])
    ->havingRaw("fullDate between '2019-08-01' and '2019-10-01'"])
    ->count();
```